# How do I make a message/method that accepts both value and reference types?

Tags: objective-c, methods, parameter-passing, value-type, reference-type

Like the question asks, how would I in Obj-C make a message that can take both reference types (object) and value types (primitives) as a parameter?

```
-(id) initWithValue: (?) val;
```

What would I write in place of the ? to make it work with both reference and value types? Or isn't it possible at all, since an `int` isn't a reference type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. If you need to do this, wrap your primitives in an object. `NSNumber` for example.